# What is npm WARN enoent ENOENT: while installing "ws" module in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, websocket

Hey I've been trying to install "ws" module but when I run `npm install ws` it gives following error,
`npm WARN  enoent ENOENT:<Folder name>   no such file or directory, open 'G:\Dead Simple\package.json'` 
Well I searched for solution , everybody answered it as you should have `package.json` file in your project directory but being a beginner I really don't what to write in that file.How should I resolve it ?

It gives me exactly this output ...
`npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\Dead Simple\package.json'
npm WARN Dead Simple No description
npm WARN Dead Simple No repository field.
npm WARN Dead Simple No README data
npm WARN Dead Simple No license field.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to write anything. At the beginning of your project when you:

```
 npm init
```

a package.json will be created, listing references to packages you have installed. Installing extra packages add them to your node_modules directory, and adds a reference to your package.json.

Comment: Hey I tried now it popped up following message.                      `G:\Sem 6\Project JS\js\Dead Simple>npm install ws --save
dead_simple@1.0.0 G:\Sem 6\Project JS\js\Dead Simple
`-- ws@2.0.3
  `-- ultron@1.1.0

npm WARN dead_simple@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN dead_simple@1.0.0 No repository field.`

Comment: please confirm you have package.json in the root of your project.