# NPM Insall error (Angular 6)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular6

I have an Angular 6 project and when I try to execute it, it throws the following error:

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\fernando.cavalcante\\Desktop\\Fernando_Backup\\VisualStudio2017\\Projects\\GerenciadorDiretorioAPI\\Presentattion".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from ...
```

I tried to update the packages but when I run `npm install` command, cmd throws the following message:

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Folder1\Projects\My.Project\Developing\0 - Presentation\My.Project\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-b75d419b\test\reg-exp\#\sticky\is-implemented.js'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 403 Forbidden: fsevents@https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.1.3.tgz

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-PFtv1/beCRQmkCfwPAlGdY92c6Q= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-PFtv1/beCRQmkCfwPAlGdY92c6Q= but got sha1-pMeCeEFUzmIX1LXY6ZTg7bwjcDY=. (4472399 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-18T13_11_28_030Z-debug.log
```

I searched some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092323/what-is-npm-warn-enoent-enoent-while-installing-ws-module-in-node-js), [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/261), [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/466) and [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/466), tried to reinstall Node, reinstall Angular and even searched in some unresolved questions but nothing worked for me.

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular) and run `npm clean cache -f` but didn't work.

I don't know how to proceed.

I'm using Angular CLI: 6.0.1 and Node: 8.11.2

Comment: What version of node are you running, and are you using angular-cli?

Comment: I'm using Angular CLI: 6.0.1 and Node: 8.11.2

Comment: You can try running `npm i -D @angular-devkit/core` or maybe have a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307) thread

Comment: It throws a several error line: `npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333003/could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete ***package-lock.json***, even with ***@angular/cli @ version 7***, I'm using *version 6*, and was having the same issue. Deleting the ***package-lock.json*** fixed this error for me. There was no need to delete ***node_modules*** as it would not even install any packages, but only throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your `node_modules` folder. `rm -rf node_modules`

Delete your package.lock.json file.

Might want to update your angular cli.

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

or first run `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` then `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Now run npm install.

Comment: It throws this error: `npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-K7g15Bb6Ra4lKf7Iq2l/I5/En+hLIHmxWZGq3D4DIRNFxMNV6j2SHSvDOqs2tGd4UvD/fJvrwopzQXjLrT7Itw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-K7g15Bb6Ra4lKf7Iq2l/I5/En+hLIHmxWZGq3D4DIRNFxMNV6j2SHSvDOqs2tGd4UvD/fJvrwopzQXjLrT7Itw== but got sha512-RHa70BV45f+STdQcnd+HMxg/xlFoZmEY4DZsUvfokR5Ts67zVcKENE4PfChk3he+4L29QUG5b7n97WGseaxr3w==. (1064527 bytes)`

Comment: Don't know what it means and have a lot of warnings after this error

Comment: Try `npm cache verify` or `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 0):

Install dev dependency.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Is a new package in Angular 6

Comment: It didn't work for me, still throwing the error message

Comment: copy the print of ng -v